# can it be the body control module

Tags: bmw, x3

i have a bmw x3 2005 e83 it started when airbags coming on and then speedo stopped and than started again and then indicatorson dashboard stop working but the indicators outside of the car work than windows stop working and windscreen wipers stopped and wing mirrors not working and now the car won't start. can any one help please gerry.

Comment: Check the grounding points under the dash, also for loose connections or broken wires.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Check the voltage at the battery. If the voltage is low, it can exhibit the symptoms you're talking about.